# Validate date text box input in extjs

Tags: validation, extjs

I have a drop down list. When I select a Date option from drop down, then the text box user input should only be in the form of mm/dd/yyy.
If anything else then throw an alert.
Any suggestions on achieving the same in ext js.

Answer (score 2):

Siddharth,

Please have a look at this. You can optimize this code according to your framework. I just made an example for your question like this:

```
var dateVar = {
        xtype     : 'datefield',
        name      : 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Date',
        emptyText: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        altFormats: 'm/d/Y',
        submitFormat: 'm/d/Y',
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        listeners: {
            blur: function(field) {
                if( ! field.isValid()) {
                    alert('Date is invalid!');
                }
            }
        }
    };
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    id : 'editTask',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    items : [{
        xtype : 'combo',
        name : "type",
        fieldLabel : 'Type',
        store : ['DATE', 'NUMBER', 'TEXT'],
        width : 500,
        emptyText : "Select..",
        listeners : {
            change : selectionChanged
        }
    }, { 
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        id :  'datefiledContainer',
    }]
});

function selectionChanged(combo){
    var dateVarCont = Ext.getCmp("datefiledContainer");
        dateVarCont.removeAll();
    if(combo.value == "DATE"){
        dateVarCont.add([dateVar]);
    }else{
        var field = {
            xtype : combo.value.toLowerCase() + "field",
            name : combo.value,
            fieldLabel : combo.value,
            width : 500
        }
        dateVarCont.add([field]);
    }

};
```

You can find the working example at following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/narendrakurapati/gDJYw/5/

thank you,

Nandu

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
    name      : 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Date',
    emptyText: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    altFormats: 'm/d/Y',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    submitFormat: 'm/d/Y',
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    listeners: {
        blur: function(field) {
            if( ! field.isValid()) {
                alert('Date is invalid!');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/qrbNT/

**But**. I think is a bad way. It is better to allow the user to enter a date in a convenient format, while the server to send in the correct format. Use "[altFormats](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-altFormats)" & "submitFormat" propertyes:

```
...
altFormats: 'U|d-m-Y|d.m.Y|d/m/Y|d,m,Y|d-m-y|d.m.y|d/m/y|m/d/Y',
submitFormat: 'm/d/Y',
...
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/z8VUH/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add a validator to the textbox like this:

```
validator: function(value){
    if((Ext.Date.parse(value, "m/d/Y") && theComboBox.getValue() == "DATE_INPUT")
        || theComboBox.getValue() != "DATE_INPUT")
        return true;
    return "Date is not in the format mm/dd/yyyy";
}
```

You will need a reference to the `combobox` that the user selects the input format from and also `DATE_INPUT` is probably not what your actual value is.